# Why is my model reflecting light like this?

Tags: 3d-view, light, reflection

I was doing simple model but when i extruded some parts they started to reflect light very  strangely. Any ideas why?[image]

Comment: Could you show a view of the model in edit mode so we can see the mesh?

Comment: That image is the rendered view so shadows will depend a lot on the lighting. What does it look like in solid mode?

Answer (score 1):

This issue must have occurred due to shade smooth. This issue is quite common. All you have to do is go into object properties -> Normals -> AutoSmooth

[image]